# How to add a value using Web.Release.config

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, app-config

In my web.config I have:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="version" value="1" />
</appSettings>
```

In my Web.Release.config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="appRoot" value="/root" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</appSettings>
```

In my app_code\GlobalVal.cshtml

```
public static readonly string appRoot = 
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appRoot"];
```

Then change the project settings to use release build profile.

The value for `@GlobalVal.appRoot` is null though. After build and publish to another machine it still is null.

How do I get to build it using the optional appRoot value using visual studio 2013 MVC application?

**[UPDATE]**

Press play in Visual studio and set a breakpoint right after setting appRoot in GlobalVal.cshtml. The build output contains: `Build started: Project: YourApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------`

But the appRoot is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the transform that needs to take place (e.g. an insert in this case):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="appRoot" value="/dirOfProduction" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Updated my question as it still isn't doing what I expect it to do.

Comment: Hrm.  I wonder if the transform only applies during a publish, as opposed to a build.

Comment: It does work when I publish to the server though. That is enough for me as the changes are only needed when the application is published.

Comment: Maybe you want to use externalised app settings during development instead?  Configure `appSettings` to refer to an external file (omitting that file from source control) and then use the transform to remove the external reference attribute, and insert the requisite settings.